# Can someone please tell me more about the 'Accessibility Mode' mentioned in User Record?

Tags: user-record

I was trying to create a Meeting request from salesforce calendar and receiving below error

"This page isn't available because you're not using the Salesforce Classic 2010 user interface theme or because Accessibility Mode is enabled. The New Meeting Request feature works only when Salesforce Classic uses the 2010 user interface theme and Accessibility Mode is disabled."

And I was able to disable the "Accessibility Mode" from user record and able to schedule the Meeting.

As per "Accessibility Mode" help its mentioning as below
"Accessibility mode is an alternate user interface mode which turns off some user interface features, such as displaying details on hover. Users using screen readers, such as JAWS or Windows-Eyes, may consider using Accessibility mode."

But I couldn't able to identify or understand why it is used or what is its purpose?

- Any simple use case or scenario to understand this?
- Is there any other impact for Switching off/on this flag in user record?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'Accessibility Mode' is a common feature in not just Salesforce Calendar but several other solutions which provide support for specially challenged e.g. for blind or visually impaired people.

The 'Accessibility Mode' allows these people to read and interpret the provided information either by converting text to speech or providing other helpful clues. If you turn it off, they do not have a means of recognising and interpreting this easily.

This is also explained [here](http://www.crmsalesforcetraining.com/enabling-accessibility-mode-in-salesforce-com/).